# Best practice to bring Material look to Preferences using AppCompat?

Tags: android, android-preferences, material-design

What is the best way to bring Material design to the preferences using AppCompat?
I've been reading some questions and the main points seem to be:

- The [official guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html)  suggest avoiding `PreferenceActivity` if working for API>11 (and I am). Instead one should use `PreferenceFragment`s;
- Using PreferenceActivity would be bad also because you can't extend both `PreferenceActivity` and `ActionBarActivity`;
- You might use a general `ActionBarActivity` and load `PreferenceFragment` (API>11) into it. This way preference widgets loaded from resources gets tinted by AppCompat, but that's not true for any widget (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26466577/apply-tint-to-preferenceactivity-widgets-with-appcompat-v21) );
- With the suggested solution, anyway, the whole UI look isn't quite Material (see image on Android 4.2), even if inheriting from AppCompat theme.
- Another way could be to extend a `PreferenceActivity` (API>1). As said, you won't extend `ActionBarActivity` but just inherit AppCompat theme.
- Last, you could just make your own Activity extending `ActionBarActivity`, and deal with widgets, layouts, margins, SharedPreferences yourself.

At the moment I am not aware of a working solution. I've seen some discussion going on in a Chris Banes post introducing Material, but no solution was suggested. I'm asking:

- Did some of you succeed in bringing a pure (as possible) Material look to preferences, and how?
- Will there be improvements  in v7 regarding this issue in the future?

[image]

Comment: "As said, you won't extend ActionBarActivity but just inherit AppCompat theme" -- that is unlikely to have any positive effect. "Will there be improvements in v7 regarding this issue in the future?" -- Google usually does not indicate what will and will not be done in the future.

Comment: I got managed to use my theme with API 21 and PreferenceFragment with devices pre-L, but still with API 22 I found no solutions for dialogs like ListPreference. They now got only the accent color but the dialog is still the old one and more other a layer is visible behind and around the dialog. Any idea for these dialogs?

Comment: I'm using [this](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs) great library for dialogs, and they have implemented custom preferences too. Take a look.

Comment: Did you use `addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs)` for this? I'm only now finding out that it's deprecated as of API <11 and running into problems sharing preferences across fragments

Comment: @Jammo addPreferencesFromResources() is not deprecated in PreferenceFragment.

Comment: @mvai Did you find any solution that is worth recommending?

Comment: @f470071 you can take a look at the new preference support libraries, particularly v14.

Comment: @mvai Nah. I have to support API 10. I have founf preference library in support library v7 but this has absolutely no documentation. Very sloppy from google.

Comment: They are easy to use but right now only the v14 version is material styled.

Comment: @natario Would you be willing to share a bit more details (.xml?) about how you created such a nice preferences view?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

I'm using `AndroidDeveloperLB/MaterialPreferenceLibrary` in my projects.

Easy to install. [Import](https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/MaterialPreferenceLibrary#import-)
Easy to use. [Sample](https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/MaterialPreferenceLibrary#sample-)